# Cannot convert value of type UILayoutPriority

Tags: ios11, swift4

I'm trying to change the priority of a constraint to be higher than that of another constraint. In Swift 4 / iOS 11, this code no longer compiles:

```
let p = self.lab2.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for:.horizontal)
self.lab1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(p+1, for: .horizontal)
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Swift 4 / iOS 11, UILayoutPriority is no longer a simple number; it's a RawRepresentable struct. You have to do your arithmetic by passing through the `rawValue` of the struct.

It may be useful to have on hand an extension such as the following:

```
extension UILayoutPriority {
    static func +(lhs: UILayoutPriority, rhs: Float) -> UILayoutPriority {
        let raw = lhs.rawValue + rhs
        return UILayoutPriority(rawValue:raw)
    }
}
```

Now the `+` operator can be used to combine a UILayoutPriority with a number, as in the past. The code in your question will now compile (and work) correctly.

**EDIT** In iOS 13 this extension is no longer needed, as it is incorporated directly into system (plus you can now initialize a UILayoutPriority without saying `rawValue:`). Still, it beats me why Apple ever thought it was a good idea to make a `priority` anything other than a number, because that is all it is or needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following to continue using them as before:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Allow to pass a float value to the functions depending on UILayoutPriority
extension UILayoutPriority: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    public typealias FloatLiteralType = Float

    public init(floatLiteral value: Float) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}

// MARK: - Allow to pass an integer value to the functions depending on UILayoutPriority
extension UILayoutPriority: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int

    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.init(Float(value))
    }
}
```

Refer to https://gist.github.com/jeremiegirault/7f73692a162b6ecf8ef60c7809e8679e for a full implementation

Comment: Very nice idea. However, it doesn't solve the use case _in my question_. My extension does solve that problem.

Comment: @matt probably the most complete solution is https://gist.github.com/jeremiegirault/7f73692a162b6ecf8ef60c7809e8679e

Comment: Good link. Might want to put that into your answer, since answers survive but comments don't.

Comment: Excellent solution